# There's no trusted peers even I connected with over 500 peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, javascript, peers, full-node

I am running Geth Ethereum node on Linux.
This is the command I used to start the node, and the synchronization is finished.

```
nohup geth --http --http.api personal,eth,net,web3,txpool \
     --ws --ws.api eth,net,web3,txpool \
     --ws.origins '*' \
     --maxpeers 10000 \
     --txpool.globalslots=250000 \
     --txpool.globalqueue=50000
```

After several hours later, I checked the trusted peers using geth attach, but there's nothing.
To every thing's clear, I checked not trusted peers and there are so many!
At that point, there is already over 500 peers.

[image]

I want to know

1. Why this thing is happening
2. What exactly trusted peers is
3. How to increase trusted peers list.

I will be very thankful if someone helps me on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the adding of new `TrustedPeers` is a manual process.

They are peers that are allowed to connect to you even if all your inbound connection slots are full.

Reference:
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-admin#admin-addtrustedpeer